# Unable to configure snippets

Tags: ace-editor

I can't use snippets and autocompilation when I use `Ace editor` in my Angular 7.X project.

When I try to config autocompile:

```
  this.editor.getEditor().setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
  });
```

I get an warning in console:

```
misspelled option "enableBasicAutocompletion"
misspelled option "enableSnippets"
misspelled option "enableLiveAutocompletion"
```

I use angular wrapper for Ace Editor: `ng2-ace-editor`.

I reproduce this error on StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pyt9cf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Add `import "brace/ext/language_tools"` to load the language tools extension which contains the functionality for snippets.
(You may need to add brace to your package.json for this to work).

Also note that the

```
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

rule you use will break the editor, by assigning different font family to the elements inside the editor